# Why is my webscraper only exporting 240 entries of the array to the CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

```
import bs4 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

   
# Creating Empty Arrays.

Phone_Number_arr = []
Location_arr = []
Email_arr = []
Name_arr = []

# Creating Global Variables

page_number = 0
web_page = ""
item_number = 1


# Web Scraping App Function.

def webscraper(web_page, page_number):
    
    # Setting the URL do its base form
    web_page = 'myUrl'
    
    # Adding the current page in regards to the Pagination
    next_page = web_page + str(page_number)
    
    # Making the GET Request
    response = requests.get(str(next_page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # Finding all the relevant classes in current page
    soup_name =  soup.findAll("h5",{"class":"nameOverflow"})
            
    # Placeholder variable for the number of hits
    number_of_hits = 1
    
    # Iterating trough all items on current page
    for x in range(len(soup_name)):

        # Appending it to the relevant array
        Name_arr.append(soup_name[x].text.strip())
        
        # Printing it to console
        for i in Name_arr:
            print(str(number_of_hits) + " == " + i + " ")
            number_of_hits += 1
        
        # Adding to the pagination count
        page_number += 1
        
    
    # IF loop to check for when the pagination pages are complete 
    if page_number <= 234:
        
        # This self-calls the function as long as there are pages left
        # in the pagination.
        webscraper(web_page, page_number)

# Calling The Function For The First Time

webscraper('myUrl', 0)

# Command To Create CSV File

with open('plumbers.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldName = ['number', 'name']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldName)
    thewriter.writeheader()
    
# Iterating trough array to populate csv file

    for plumbers in Name_arr:
        thewriter.writerow({'number': item_number, 'name': plumbers})
        item_number += 1
```

I have this webscraper built with Python. It is beautiful. I'm pretty proud of it. It exports all entries to the command line when I run the program with PowerShell. The only problem is the export function only exports the first 240 entries of the array. The array should have several thousand entries. I don't really understand why the CSV does not have all the entries of the array?

Comment: Are you sure ```Name_arr``` contains thousands of entries? If not, you should really be asking why your scraper falls to scrape more entries. Did you inspect the http response to make sure you aren't being rate-limited or something?

Comment: It's also not a good idea to use recursion instead of a loop.

Comment: Sometimes webpages contain a dynamic loaders that fetch more data as you scroll down the page. Look at the webpage with a debugger and see XHR and other network activity. Example IKEA: data is fetched as JSON in the background, with offset and amount, filling the page dynamically.  This is more effective for humans. The days of 1000 entry lists are probably gone 20 years ago.

Comment: You removed it but your URL had a page number in the string hardcoded, check if your create the URL for the next page correctly.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm getting thousands of entries exported to the console. Unless the entries are exported to console but not entered into the array.

Comment: Let me try removing the recursion function and using a loop instead. Maybe that solves the problem.

Comment: Nope still the same result.

Comment: omg the array does only have 240 entries... why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems my logic was just a little bit convoluted. I finally got it working with this code.

```
import bs4 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

   
# Creating Empty Arrays.

Phone_Number_arr = []
Location_arr = []
Email_arr = []
Name_arr = []

# Creating Global Variables

page_number = 0
web_page = ""
item_number = 1
number_of_hits = 1


# Web Scraping App Function.

while page_number <= 234: 
    
    # Setting the URL do its base form
    web_page = 'https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=plumbers&pg='
    
    # Adding the current page in regards to the Pagination
    next_page = web_page + str(page_number)
    
    # Making the GET Request
    response = requests.get(str(next_page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # Finding all the relevant classes in current page
    soup_name =  soup.findAll("h5",{"class":"nameOverflow"})
            
    
    for x in range(len(soup_name)):
        Name_arr.append(soup_name[x].text.strip())
        print("added " + str(soup_name[x].text.strip()))
    
    page_number += 1

print(*Name_arr, sep = "\n")

with open('plumbers.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldName = ['number', 'name']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldName)
    thewriter.writeheader()
    
# Iterating trough array to populate csv file

    for plumbers in Name_arr:
        thewriter.writerow({'number': item_number, 'name': plumbers})
        item_number += 1
```

Comment: To improve your answer, please explain what you changed so people reading this in the future don't have to hunt through both codes to see what made it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could print `len(Name_arr)` either in your console or write it to your csv. It looks like you’re fixing your csv to be the length of Name_arr rather than exporting the whole dataset. If you’re able to use pandas or add the library to your environment you could try using a pandas dataframe instead and exporting with `df.to_csv`. See documentation [df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Forgive me if this formatting is a bit off I’m new to the platform and trying it out on mobile.